Is the savepoint directory enough to restart and resume an Apache Flink job?
In Apache Flink, when using the flag --fromSavepoint, do I have to specify the exact path or is the state.savepoints.dir i.e. the root dir enough?
I notice that each savepoint creates a sub directory under state.savepoints.dir
If state.savepoints.dir is not enough, then is there a way to figure out the latest savepoint besides parsing and storing the result of ./bin/flink stop b/w k8s deployments?

exact path is required:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/cli/#starting-a-job-from-a-savepoint
./bin/flink run \
  --detached \ 
  --fromSavepoint /tmp/flink-savepoints/savepoint-cca7bc-bb1e257f0dab \
  ./examples/streaming/StateMachineExample.jar

